# all JQuery functions lost on partial postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an aspx page (the JQuery.js is called in the masterpage for this). Now this is linked to the http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

In this page I have an updatepanel which is dynamically loading different usercontrols which in turn have their own JS files loads (using scriptmanager). Now on a partial postback I am losing JQuery functions (for instance .val returns undefined).

```
[code]
function pageLoad(){
    //whatever you want to do on partial postback
    //alert('partial handler');

    $(jutb).watermark('Username or Email address');
    $(jptb).watermark('Password');

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}


// Called when async postback begins
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    // alert("You are in the InitializeRequestHandler function.");  // breakpoint here
}

// Called when async postback ends
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    // this function is run after an Ajax partial postback occurs

    loadUsername();
    loadPassword();

    if (args.get_error() != undefined)
        alert("There was an error" + args.get_error().message);

    return;
}
[/code]
```

my page load is being called in the partial postback. (i.e. I can alert to it.)

I have a linkbutton which triggers some JS code. after the partial postback if I try it .val returns undefined.

Any ideas why JQuery is being lost?

Answer (score 1):

When you get the response back from the server into your update panel, all event handler bindings you did the first time the page loaded are broken, because those are new elements now, even though they satisfy the same selection criteria.

You can try to re-run your event handler binding - you can create some kind of `init` JS function that you'd call in your `EndRequestHandler`.

Other way, and probably better, would be to use jQuery's `on` to bind your elements to event handlers. Take a look here on how to use it:

https://api.jquery.com/on/